# Why is this CSS layout causing the wrapper container to have a top margin

Tags: css, layout, html

My question regards the code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoYmZz

The wrapper div is showing the yellow background (what appears to look like a margin) above the header div. I'm curious as to why this is happening.

I have tried setting the `margin` and `padding` to `0` for both. I've actually set it to `0` on every element in the code: `html, body, #header, #footer, etc`

The yellow still shows.

However, when I apply zero margins and padding globally,

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

this can be prevented, and I can just add some small margins and padding on the wrapper container instead,

```
#wrapper { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

as such with this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNKGvz

My question is why is this happening, and how can I get the result of the second codepen without monkey-patching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `margin` on your `h2` elements.

```
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

will fix it.

Comment: Feel free to smack me, now.
Thanks, Paul!

Comment: Setting the h2's margin to 0 will fix the yellow part, but you will need :
'body{margin:0;}'
to get rid of the white margin around your wrapper.